# Bare-Bones implementation of printf

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, formatting

I made a bare-bones implementation of `printf` based on an exercise in Chapter 7, problem 5 of "Pointers on C" by Kenneth A. Reek. What criticism do you have of my writing style?

For instance, do you find I added far too many header files in code. Should I add `#ifndef` guards for the header files? Do you find any of the functions throughout the implementation too difficult too read?

For instance, the `myprintf` function is the most important function, as it takes advantage of all other functions throughout the program. Is the way `myprintf` is implemented with switch statements too messy?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1000

void reverse (char *s) {
    char temp;  

    for ( int i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = temp;
    }
}


char * printd(long long int n)
{

  static char d[1000];
  static char abs[1000];
  static char * abs_p = abs;
  static int sign;
  if ( n < 0 )
  {
    *d = ('-');
    n = -n;
  }

  while ( lldiv(n,10).quot != 0)
  {
    *abs_p++ = (lldiv(n,10).rem+'0');

    n = (lldiv(n,10).quot);

  }

  reverse(abs);
  strcat(d,abs);

  return d;
}

char * lltoa(long long int n)
{
    static char s[MAX_LENGTH];

    long long int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0) /* record sign */
        n = -n;     /* make n positive by n =-n */
    i = 0;
    do      /* generate digits in reverse order */
    {
        s[i++] = lldiv(n,10).rem + '0'; /* get next digit with n % 10 + '0'; */

    } while (n = lldiv(n,10).quot, n > 0);       /* delete it with while ( (n /= 10) > 0 )*/

    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);

    return s;

}

char * lltoa2(long long int n)
{

  char d[MAX_LENGTH];
  char abs[MAX_LENGTH];
  char * abs_p = abs;
  int sign;
  if ( n < 0 )
  {
    *d = ('-');
    n = -n;
  }

  while (lldiv(n,10).quot != 0)
  {
    *abs_p++ = (lldiv(n,10).rem+'0');

    n = (lldiv(n,10).quot);

  } 

    *abs_p++ = (lldiv(n,10).rem+'0'); /* first digit after pos or neg sign must be included */

  reverse(abs); /* contents of abs are originally in reverse order of input */
  d[0] = '\0';
  strcat(d,abs);

  return &d[0];
}

double nround(double input, double power)
{

    double marge = pow(10,power);

    double up = input * marge;

    double result = ((double)(llround(up)))/marge;

    return result;

}

// ftoa rounds accurately up to 15 digits, guranteed

// ftoa can only deal with integral values with an absolute value less than or equal to LLONG_MAX

/* ftoa only works until 9.9999999999999999e15 rounded to

zero decimal places

*/
char * ftoa(const double input, const double power) // pow is the '*' in "%.*f"
{

  const double in = nround(input,power); 

  static char a[MAX_LENGTH] = "\0";

  int j = 0;

  while (j < strlen(a) ) a[j++] = '\0';

  long long int f_to_i = (long long int)(in); 

  strcat(a,lltoa(f_to_i)); strcat(a,".");

  double integral = 0;

  double fraction = 0;

 (in >= 0) ? (fraction = modf(in,&integral)): (fraction = modf(-in,&integral)); /* stores fractional part of input */

  char non_zero_mantissa[1000] = "\0"; /* stores non-zero digits in mantissa after leading zeros following decimal point */

  strcat(non_zero_mantissa,lltoa(llround(fraction*pow(10,power))));


  int i = strlen(non_zero_mantissa);

  while ( i++ < power )
  {
    strcat(a,"0");

  }

  strcat(a,non_zero_mantissa);

    return a;

#if 0
    int c = 0;

    while ( a[c] != '\0') putchar(a[c++]);
#endif
}

//#if 0
int myprintf(char const * s,...)
{

  va_list var_arg;

  char * s_p = (char *)(s-1);

  va_start(var_arg,s);

  int ROUND_TO = 0;

  char rounding[1000];

  while (*++s_p != '\0')
  {
    switch(*s_p)
    {
        case '%':
            {
            switch(*++s_p)
            {

                case 'f':
                    {
                    char const * f_p = ftoa(va_arg(var_arg,double),6);
                    while ( *f_p != '\0') putchar(*f_p++);
                    break;
                    }
                case 'd':
                    {
                    char const * d_p = (char *)lltoa(va_arg(var_arg,long long int));
                    while ( *d_p != '\0') putchar(*d_p++);
                    break;
                    }
                case 's':
                    {
                    char const * string_p = va_arg(var_arg,char *);
                    while ( *string_p != '\0') putchar(*string_p++);
                    break;
                    }
                case 'c':
                    {
                    putchar((char)va_arg(var_arg,int));
                    break;
                    }
                case '.':
                    {
                        if (isdigit(*(s_p+1))) //peek after '.' and see if there is a digit
                        {
                            ROUND_TO = 1;

                            int i = 0;

                            char * r_p = rounding;

                            while (isdigit(*++s_p)) { *r_p++ = *s_p; }

                            *r_p = '\0';

                            if ( *s_p == 'f' ) 
                            {
                                myprintf("%s",ftoa(va_arg(var_arg,double),atoi(rounding)));
                                ++s_p;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                putchar('%');

                                putchar(*s_p);

                                myprintf("%s",atoi(rounding));

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            putchar('%');

                            putchar(*s_p++);
                        }



                    }
                default:
                    {
                    putchar(*s_p);
                    break;
                    }
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            {
            putchar(*s_p);
            break;
            }


  }

}


  va_end(var_arg);
  return 1;
}

//#endif

//#if 0
int main(void) 
{

#if 0
    ftoa(-3.9999,3);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-1.5555,2);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-3.39823929,5);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-3.0000000000000099,15);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-3.6666666666666666,15);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-3.4545,3);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-3.454599,5);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(-1.0000000000000009,15);
    putchar('\n');

    ftoa(3.9999,3);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(1.5555,2);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(3.39823929,5);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(3.0000000000000099,15);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(3.6666666666666666,15);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(3.4545,3);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(3.454599,5);
    putchar('\n');
    ftoa(1.0000000000000009,15);
    putchar('\n');

    ftoa(9.9999999999999999e15,14); //FAILS!!!
    putchar('\n');

myprintf("Thatcher Swag\n%s\n%f\n%c\n%d\n","Swiss Cheese",3.45,'T',3535232523);

double a = 3.14, b = 325.3235, c = 790.866;
myprintf("My bank account amount: %f\n",c);

double light_speed = 3.0e8; 

double planck_mass = 2.17647051*pow(10,-8); 

myprintf("Speed of light: %f\n",light_speed*planck_mass);

printf("Speed of light: %f\n",light_speed*planck_mass); //TESTS PASS

myprintf("%f\n",planck_mass);

printf("%f\n",planck_mass); //TESTS_PASS
#endif
myprintf("%.5f\n",43.235278);
myprintf("%.5f\n",3.14159265);
myprintf("%.3f\n",4.9999);
myprintf("%.10f\n",1558.2392038592972022352698);
myprintf("%.15f\n",1.2392038592972022352698); //myprintf can only round a floating-point that has 15 digits, including before mantissa or less
myprintf("%f\n",323.3435);
myprintf("%s %c %.3f %d\n","Swiss",'A',123.3257,1325352);

myprintf("%s\n",lltoa2(32235235));
myprintf("%s\n",lltoa2(232362351));
myprintf("%s\n",lltoa2(LLONG_MAX));
myprintf("My parents gave me %d hot dogs for July 4\n",359);

}
//#endif
```

Comment: A good starting point is to look at the actual implementation of [GNU C library functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (download the archive file). In this case, look under `stdio-common/` and you'll see that `printf()` is a wrapper around `vprintf()`, which goes to `vfprintf()`. If you open `stdio-common/vfprintf.c`, you'll see their implementation details.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Answer (score 6):

There is so much going on here that needs improvement that the correctness of converting `double` to a *string* has not been assessed yet.  I am doubtful that its correctly rounds edge cases.  Example

```
myprintf("%f\n",0.00000049999999999999993); --> 0.000001
// expect 0.000000
```

---

> ... I added far too many header files in code(?)

This is a minor concern.  Adding some extra *standard C header files* is rarely a significant mistake.

> Should I add #ifndef guards for the header files?

Code should have 3 portions: myprintf.c for `int myprintf(char const * s,...)`, myprintf.h for its declaration and other important constants, defines, non-static functions and a `main.c/test.c` to show how to use and test `myprintf()`.

myprintf.h should use guards.

> Do you find any of the functions throughout the implementation too difficult too read?

Yes.

Opinion: too much vertical white-space.

Strange use of magic numbers. Why `1000` when `MAX_LENGTH` or another mcaro-constant could be used.  Avoid naked magic numbers like `1000`

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 1000
....
static char d[1000];
```

Mixed use of `static`.  In both cases, better code would pass in the buffer and eschew `static` buffers.

```
static char s[MAX_LENGTH]; // in lltoa()
char d[MAX_LENGTH]; // in lltoa2()
```

Re-use of very common functions name for a non-function with `char abs[MAX_LENGTH];`.  `abs()` is a very common standard function and use here as a non-function is very distracting.

Unexplained `#if 0` blocks of code.  If not needed, then delete them before review.  Similar issue of `//#if 0`.

Inconsistent indent depth increment.  Sometimes it is 2, sometimes 4.  Hmmmm.

Inconsistent vertical white-space.  Tip: use an auto formatter.  Life is too short to do this/maintain this by hand.

> Is the way myprintf is implemented with switch statements too messy?

`case '.':` is certainly messy.

---

### Errors

**Failure with various values**

`myprintf("%d\n",LLONG_MIN);` --> `"-(\n"`.
`myprintf("%f\n",DBL_MAX);` --> `"-9223372036854.775391\n"`
`myprintf("%f\n",-0.0);` `"0.000000\n"`, expected `"-0.000000\n"`.
Use `signbit()` rather than `if (sign < 0)`.

**Invalid test**

`myprintf("%s %c %.3f %d\n","Swiss",'A',123.3257,1325352);` passes `1325352` which is an `int` or `long`, yet `long long` expected.  Result: UB.

**Strange use of `llround()`**

Unclear why code uses limits computation

```
// double result = ((double)(llround(up)))/marge;
double result = (round(up))/marge;
```

**Failure with 0**

`lltoa2(0)` return an empty string.  Use a `do{} while` loop instead.

**Code lacks a test driver**

All the `myprintf()` oblige a in person review of output rather than an automatic one.  Test code should compare against the regular `printf()`.  Idea: at the top of `myprintf()`, add code with `vprintf()`, then a personal review only need to sight compare pairs of output to see if they math.

Better: re-write code to `mysprintf()` and then compare string results with `sprintf()`.

The key point is that to write a good `myprintf()`, you need a mini-tester jig (harness) so automated testing of millions of combination are possible.

### Easy stuff

**Enable *all* compiler warnings**

Here are some of what came up for me - without even reading the code.
Save time, enable all warnings.

Why `sign`?

```
// warning: unused variable 'sign' [-Wunused-variable]
static int sign;
```

Undefined behavior to return address of local object.  **This is the biggest error.** Until I corrected this, code would not run - and it was so easy to find.

```
//  warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
char d[MAX_LENGTH];
return &d[0];
```

Why `ROUND_TO`?

```
// warning: variable 'ROUND_TO' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
int ROUND_TO = 0;
```

### Small stuff

**Undefined behavior**

`n = -n;` is undefined behavior when `n == LLONG_MAX` in `lltoa2().`

**Replicated use of `lldiv()`**

Instead of 2 calls `lldiv()`, use one.  Or better just code `n/10` and `n%10`.  Good compilers will see that and emit one piece of code to calculate both.

**`reverse(s)` unnecessary**

Just build string form the end toward the front.

**Support functions should be `static`**

Once code is segmented into `myprintf()` and the rest, functions like `lltoa2()` should be `static` to minimize names space pollution.

**Odd code**

`d[0] = '\0'; strcat(d,abs);` is same as simpler `strcpy(d,abs);`

Why `"\0"` vs `""`?

```
// static char a[MAX_LENGTH] = "\0";
static char a[MAX_LENGTH] = "";
```

**Use of `int` vs. `size_t`**

`size_t` is neither too narrow nor too wide for array indexing and sizing.  `int` , in general, may be insufficient.  Code like `int j = 0; while (j < strlen(a) ) a[j++] = '\0';` raises distracting warnings about mixing `int/unsigned` math.  Instead:

```
size_t j = 0; while (j < strlen(a) ) {
  a[j++] = '\0';
}
```

**Avoid calling `strlen()` in a loop.**

A weak compiler will call `strlen(a)` over and over.  Each call costs the length of the string.

```
// int j = 0;
//while (j < strlen(a) ) a[j++] = '\0';
// instead
size_t j = 0;
while (a[j]) {
  a[j++] = '\0';
}
// or simply
memset(a, 0, strlen(a));
```

On 2nd thought: `while (j < strlen(a) ) a[j++] = '\0';` does nothing useful after 
`static char a[MAX_LENGTH] = "\0";` as `strlen(a)` is 0.

**Review `printf()` signature**

`printf()` uses  `restrict`.  This may be advanced for OP at this time, but worthy of research.

```
int myprintf(char const * s,...)
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

---

***Recommendation:***

You are attempting one of the most challenging function re-writes - a bold task.  I commend you on your bravery.

Try again with just integer types.  After completing that, move on to floating-point.

Comment: Very good review. I only have one thing to add, and that is to avoid the `atoi` family of functions since they don't have proper error handling upon encountering unexpected input, which will be extra important here. Should be swapped out for `strtol` family of functions.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed.  There are many places assuming benign input.  Robust code would instead gracefully handle extreme/hostile input.

Comment: @chux thank you for review , can you put complete code here?

Comment: @AminM Your [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197766/bare-bones-implementation-of-printf/197767?noredirect=1#comment381415_197767) is unclear.  Are you asking for me to post a complete well functioning code for `myprintf()`?

Answer (score 3):

Some small items, additional to the great review by Chux.

- You don't seem to use anything from `<assert.h>` or `<float.h>`, so no need to include those.
- The missing features are not documented anywhere, so we have to guess what subset of `printf()` is supported.
- Test cases are missing for ±∞ and not-a-number values with the `%f` specifier.
- Precision specifiers don't work properly with `%s`:

  ```
  myprintf("%.5s", "abcdefg");  // crashes
  ```
- Unnecessary obfuscation: `*(s_p+1)` is much more recognisable when written as `s_p[1]`.
- The fallthrough from `case '.'` to `default` causes the second conversion specifier to be printed literally in this example (and could be even more serious if the second conversion were `%%`):

  ```
  myprintf("%.1f%f\n", 1.0, 0.0);
  ```

Comment: "Test cases  ... null pointers with the %s specifier": Hmmm.  As `printf("%s", (void*) NULL)` is UB, testing `myprintf()` would seem optional, though perhaps informative, as any result would match UB.

Comment: Yes, that is UB, so doesn't need a test case.  I confess I was thinking ahead to an implementation of `%p` - it's useful to have a distinct representation for null pointers there.  I'll remove that recommendation.